# How to use Protocol Buffers Serialised Data in memory?

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Consider the following code snippet.

```
DynamicMessage message; // somehow I created the message
// Writing directly to file
message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("out.ser"));
// Wrinting through other stream
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(baos);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out2.ser"));
writer.write(baos.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Now if I try to parse the same files using

```
DynamicMessage message2 = DynamicMessage.parsefrom(descriptor, "out.ser"); // Works
DynamicMessage message3 = DynamicMessage.parsefrom(descriptor, "out2.ser"); // Doesn't Work
```

I think in the `.toString()` method has changed the encoding (possibly). Can anyone please suggest a way to serialize the `message.writeTo()` to a string(Should be able to parse again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to "out2.ser" is not working because you are doing the `baos.toString()`.

protobuf's contents must be saved as byte array.

modify below code block

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(baos);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out2.ser"));
writer.write(baos.toString());
```

as

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("out2.ser");
message.writeTo(f);
```

Comment: I want the output as a String so writing as a file will be little or no use. Is there any way to use the output in memory(Maybe as a string, suggest other data types if familiar).
Thanks,

Comment: @Ran maybe you could make custom de/serializer to serialize `DynamicMessage` as `json` string, then creating `DynamicMessage` back. Just saving with `toString()` cannot deserialized back

Comment: @Ran Protobuf encoding is binary, not text. If you try to decode it as UTF-8 text and then re-encode it, you'll corrupt the data. If you really need the message as text, you could use base64 encoding to convert the binary data to text in a safe (but not readable) way, or you could use Protobuf's TextFormat class to produce text that is human-readable (but is much slower to create and to parse).

Comment: @KentonVarda thanks for the information. But the information you gave is in other direction to the question I posted.
My question was to use the serailised data without using external data structure like `file`. Simply


`DynamicMessage message; // somehow I created the message

message.writeTo(SomeInMemoryDataStructure);

DynamicMessage message2 = DynamicMessage.parsefrom(descriptor, SomeInMemoryDataStructure); // Should Work`

Comment: @Ran You said you wanted a `String`, but strings are always text. If you just want something in-memory (not necessarily a string), you can use `message.toByteArray()` (returns `byte[]`) or `message.toByteString()` (returns `com.google.protobuf.ByteString`). Either of these types can be parsed by passing to `MessageType.parseFrom()`.